# When a car is coming to a stop is there any resistance offered by it to stay in motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, inertia

Suppose a car is in a state of uniform motion moving at a high velocity and then begins slowing down due to force exerted by the brakes on the car. Will the car offer any resistance due to its inertia to try to continue its motion?

Comment: I would say that the force due to brakes on car is always zero .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does!
That's the reason why brakes have to be applied, if brakes are not applied the car would move for some distance even if foot is lifted from the accelerator due to inertia .

Answer (score 1):

The car doesn't stop Instantly when the brakes are applied and this happens because of inertia.

If the car had no inertia, it would have stopped instantly even if a minute force was applied.

Hope it helps .